# Showing that a Riemann Integrable Function is Continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, riemann-integration

I'm a grad student who's having a little trouble proving this sort of problem in my intermediate analysis course.

I have $f(x)$ defined as a Riemann integrable function in R defined on some inclusive interval [b,c]. 
$$F(x)=\int_{b}^{x} f(w) dw $$
I need to DIRECTLY show that my function, $f(x)$ is continuous on $(b , c) $
Is there any way to do this **without** using the fundamental of calculus?

Comment: I assume you don't mean $f$ itself (since it might not be continuous), but the integral from $b$ to $x$. It is problematic that you denote it by $f$ again. Give it another name.

Comment: Did you really mean to use a small $f$ in both cases, as opposed to $F(x) = \displaystyle \int_b^x f(w)\, dw$?

Comment: you're both right. my bad! I'm going to edit my post.

Comment: Your title is misleading. There are plenty of discontinuous Riemann integrable functions.

Comment: Just because $f$ is Riemann integrable does not mean it is continuous. Did you mean $F$ instead of $f$ above???

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the fundamental theorem of calculus here, this is an easier statement. If $f$ is Riemann integrable then it is bounded. Let $M=\sup\{|f(t)|: t\in [b,c]\}$. Then for $x\in (b,c)$ and a sufficiently small $h$:

$|F(x+h)-F(x)|=|\int_b^{x+h} f(t)dt-\int_b^x f(t)dt|=|\int_x^{x+h} f(t)dt|\leq\int_x^{x+h} |f(t)|dt\leq\int_x^{x+h} Mdt=M(x+h-x)=Mh\to 0$

Which proves continuity at the point $x$. Similarly you can prove one sided continuity at the corners of the interval.